# PHP array count unique occurrences of value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
$booking_array = array(

    "2018-09-01"=>array("360","360","360"),
    "2018-09-02"=>array("360","360"),
    "2018-09-03"=>array("360","520"),
    "2018-09-04"=>array("360","360"),
    "2018-09-05"=>array("360","520","520"),

);

echo '<pre>',print_r($booking_array),'</pre>';
```

I want to get only the highest number of occurrences of a specific value in the whole array.

So for example the highest number of occurrences for "360" is "3", and for "520" it is "2".

I'm using array_count_values like so:

```
foreach($booking_array as $key => $val) {

    print_r(array_count_values($val));

}
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [360] => 3
)

Array
(
    [360] => 2
)

Array
(
    [360] => 1
    [520] => 1
)

Array
(
    [360] => 2
)

Array
(
    [360] => 1
    [520] => 2
)
```

But I don't understand how I can take the **highest values only and transform this into**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 360
    [1] => 360
    [2] => 360
    [3] => 520
    [4] => 520
)
```

Comment: You should include your code with array_count_values. But yes, I believe that is the best method here.

Comment: I haven't written it yet, I just wanted to know if that was the only solution

Comment: Well SO is not a free coding site. We solve problems with code that exist. However if you do post the code in your question and it works, your question is off topic since there is no problem with it. If that is the case you can post it on code review.

Comment: Done, added the array count code

Comment: How do you want to handle edge cases: row has no values, row has no strictly highest value, interpretation of negative values, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we create a little function to make the things easier:

```
 function mergeIfGreaterThan($x,$y){
    /*
        this function merge two arrays .Each existing value of $x is 
        replaced by its corresponding in $y if it is greater than it.If a value doesn't
        exist in $x  but exists in $y it is automatically added to $x
    */
    if(!is_array($x)||!is_array($y)) return false;
    foreach($x as $k=>$v){
        if(isset($y[$k])){
            if($y[$k]>$v)
                $x[$k]=$y[$k];
            unset($y[$k]);
        }

    }
    if(!empty($y))
    foreach($y as $k=>$v){
        $x[$k]=$v;
    }
    return $x;
}
```

given this array:

```
$booking_array = array(

    "2018-09-01"=>array("360","360","360"),
    "2018-09-02"=>array("360","360"),
    "2018-09-03"=>array("360","520"),
    "2018-09-04"=>array("360","360"),
    "2018-09-05"=>array("360","520","520"),

);
```

we handle it like this:

```
$x=array();//create an empty array
foreach($booking_array as $value){//grab the max number of occurences of each value 
    $x=mergeifgreaterthan($x,array_count_values($value)); 
}
$result=array();//create another empty array to contain the result
foreach($x as $k=>$v){//loop through the array of number of occurences
    for($i=$v;$i>0;$i--){//append the value to the result array the number of times each value occurs
        $result[]=$k;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 360
    [1] => 360
    [2] => 360
    [3] => 520
    [4] => 520
)
```

Comment: This is a really bad answer! Answers should include some text explaining what the code does. The answer could be bad (i.e. not really bad) if the variable names at least showed something to indicate what they are.

Comment: @TheBobster i'm happy that this work for you.Please take alook at the edit and replace the old version of mergeIfGreaterthan function by this new one...

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the easiest way to find the values you want.

This uses array_count_values and sorts the array descending and grabs the first item key.

```
foreach($booking_array as $booking) {
    $array_count=array_count_values($booking);
    arsort($array_count); // sort it descending
    $result[] = key($array_count);  // get first items key
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/WrkRf

Comment: Hi your code doesn't produce the expected output.Try to improve it .

Comment: @Elementary Sure it does. The array with one of each is not part of OPs scope. He has not even answered the question in comments how to handle it.

Comment: @Elementary and keep note that yours does not produce the correct output "either". See item [3] has no "520" yet it's the most occuring....

Comment: @Elementary I see what you mean, but that is probably due to the question OP has not yet answered

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Steps

Step 1 : Create one Multidimensional Array to store Values and There Hightest Number of Presence

Step 2 : Go for Forloop or Foreach to Travese the Array

Step 3 : Find max from the Array and update the Multidimensional Array

Step 4 : Use the Multidimensional Array to Print as you required

if you have 5 presence of 320 and 3 presence of 540 then just

```
    $a=array();
    for($i=0;$i>arraycount;$i++)
       {
          array_push($a,"value");
       }

    print_r($a);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$booking_array = array(

    "2018-09-01"=>array("520","360","360","360"),
    "2018-09-02"=>array("360","360"),
    "2018-09-03"=>array("360","520"),
    "2018-09-04"=>array("360","360"),
    "2018-09-05"=>array("360","520","520"),

);

echo '<pre>',print_r($booking_array),'</pre>';

foreach($booking_array as $booking) {
    $array_count=array_count_values($booking);
    $value = max($array_count);
    $key = array_search($value, $array_count);
    echo $key.'--'.$value.'times'.'<br/>';

}
```

Try this

Comment: _"Try this"_ answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future researchers.  Please make a habit of including some explanation with every answer that you post.  No question or answer is so basic that a code-only answer is enough.  If you are going to keep this answer on this page, please improve it.